# Assign a string pointer in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm learning about C and having trouble with this. It does compile but the result is unexpected.
In my code, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *title[50];
    float price;
} Book;
```

In the main, I am asking the user for number of books they want to have in the library. Then let them initialize the attributes of each book.
Finally, print them out to the terminal using `Display` function.

```
void Display(Book* lib, int n);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of books:\n" );
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid number of book.");
        return 1;
    }

    Book *lib = (Book *) malloc(n * sizeof(Book));
    if(lib == NULL) {
        printf("The memory is full");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        char title[50];
        float price;
        printf("Book no.%d\n", i);
        printf("Book Title: ");
        scanf("%s", title);
        printf("Book Price: ");
        scanf("%f", &price);
        printf("\n");
        *(lib+i)->title = title;
        (lib+i)->price = price;
    }

    Display(lib, n);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles successfully, but the result is like this:

```
Enter the number of books:
2
Book no.0
Book Title: AAAA
Book Price: 1.0

Book no.1
Book Title: BBBB
Book Price: 9.9


----Displaying----
Book no.0
Book Title: BBBB
Book Price: $1.000000

Book no.1
Book Title: BBBB
Book Price: $9.900000
```

The title of the first book is wrong and it is the title of the second book.
Why does this happen? And how should I fix it?
Thank you

**Edit**: One of the requirements in my assignment is the title of `Book` must be of type `char*`

**Edit 2**: I realized my mistake when having 50 pointers of type char now. How should I fix it?

Comment: `char *title[50];` that's not a string pointer; that's *50* string pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. I thought string is an array of char in C, that's why I have `char *title[50]`. Should I allocate it by malloc?

Comment: why do you need the `char title[50];` at all. you have allocated in the heap scanf to the heap no need for this char array and fix the title to be char title[50 not char* title[50] in the struct definition

Comment: Thank you all. But having `title` of type `char*` is actually one of the requirements in my assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your struct defintion:

```
typedef struct {
    char *title[50];
    float price;
} Book;
```

You don't have an array of `char` (which can hold a string) but an array of pointers to `char` each of which can point to a string.

Also, this doesn't do what you expect due to the definition of the `price` member:

```
*(lib+i)->title = title;
```

Change the definition to:

```
typedef struct {
    char title[50];
    float price;
} Book;
```

And read directly into the struct fields instead of temp variables to avoid copying:

```
    printf("Book Title: ");
    scanf("%s", lib[i].title);
    printf("Book Price: ");
    scanf("%f", &lib[i].price);
```

Alternately, you can define `title` as a `char *`:

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
    float price;
} Book;
```

In which case you have to allocate space for the pointer to point to:

```
    lib[i].title = malloc(50);
    printf("Book Title: ");
    scanf("%s", lib[i].title);
```

Note that you can't have it point to a local like you did before because that local goes out of scope at the end of the loop, making the pointer invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But one of the requirements in my assignment is `Book` must have a title of type `char`.

Comment: @Duke_ngn I think you're misunderstanding your requirement.  A string is stored in a `char` array, for example `char title[50]`.  That's what the code above has.

Comment: I am sorry. I mistyped. The requirement of my assignment is `title` is of type `char*`. Like we have to use a pointer here

Comment: Thank you. It works now! I'm just curious but can you explain why my original code produces that result instead of crashing.

Comment: @Duke_ngn Each book's title was pointing to the same local variable in the `for` loop.  You were "lucky" that the memory used by that variable wasn't overwritten with something else when you printed the list.  Just because the code *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! That's very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a pointer, you'll need to use dynamic allocation.

The structure member should be declared as a pointer, not an array of pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
    float price;
} Book;
```

Then the loop should allocate memory for a copy of the title, and copy the title into it.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        char title[50];
        float price;
        printf("Book no.%d\n", i);
        printf("Book Title: ");
        scanf("%s", title);
        printf("Book Price: ");
        scanf("%f", &price);
        printf("\n");
        (lib+i)->title = malloc(strlen(title)+1); // +1 for the trailing null
        strcpy((lib+i)->title, title);
        (lib+i)->price = price;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you updated your post the declaration of the data member `title` of the structure

```
typedef struct {
    char *title[50];
    float price;
} Book;
```

is incorrect (in the context of the program it does not make sense). The structure should look like

```
typedef struct {
    char title[50];
    float price;
} Book;
```

That is each book has one title and not 50 pointers to titles.

And instead of this statement

```
*(lib+i)->title = title;
```

you have to write at least like

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( ( lib+i )->title, title );
```

As for your output then you assigned the address of the same local variable title to the first pointer of the array

```
    char *title[50];
```

of each element of the dynamically allocated array.

Pay attention to that you should free the dynamically allocated memory when it is not used any more. For example

```
free( lib );
```

> Edit: One of the requirements in my assignment is the title of Book
>   must be of type char*

After you updated your post then in this case the structure definition should look like

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
    float price;
} Book;
```

And you will need to allocate dynamically memory for entered title of an object of the structure.

You could do it for example the following way. I suppose that you want to use pointers instead of the subscript operator.

```
( lib + i )->title = malloc( strlen( title ) + 1 );
strcpy( ( lib + i )->title, title );
```

In this case before freeing the allocated array pointed to by the pointer lib you will need to free also each allocated character array like for example

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    free( ( lib + i )->title );
}

free( lib );
```

Comment: why he need to use the `strcpy` at all?? scanf directly to the `heap` (to the lib allocated array) no need for this

Comment: @Adam I did not say that he needs. But he uses the local variable title to enter a string.

Comment: cos he is begginer and u should correct and lead him! :-)

Comment: @Adam  I see nothing wrong to use a local variable for this purpose.

Comment: think again. its not efficient. cos first he scanf to local variable and then he copy it to the array allocated on the heap. now this is very ""smart""

Comment: @Adam It is inefficient only for low-qualified programmers that start to optimize what does not require an optimization. The local variable can be used to make various checks before storing it  in an element of the array.

Comment: why not to check all the smart things and advanced things for advanced programmers on the heap?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you so much. Your answer is extremely helpful! But why it needs to be the length of title + 1? Why it is not just `strlen(title)` when you allocate the memory?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just edited my above comment with an additional question. Could you check that please

Comment: @Duke_ngn One more byte is required if you want to store a string that includes the terminating zero character '\0'. Otherwise the array will not contain a string that will create some difficulties to output it instead of for example simple puts( ( lib + i )->title );

Comment: Thank you once again!